# How to loop through months in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, while-loop

I'm trying to generate a list of string dates in months 
(i.e. ["Oct 2014", "Nov 2014",... "Jan 2015" ]) 
using the code here:

```
var resultList = [];
var date = new Date("October 13, 2014");
var endDate = new Date("January 13, 2015");
var monthNameList = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

while (date <= endDate)
{
    var stringDate = monthNameList[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();
    resultList.push(stringDate);
    date.setDate(date.getMonth() + 1);
}

return resultList;
```

But when I run the code, the screen was frozen (like it was endless loop or something).
I never have this problem when I generate daily date (i.e. date.getDate() +1 ). 
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is within your `date.setDate(date.getMonth() + 1)` code as the MDN documentation states the [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) function sets the *day* to the specified `Date` object. Therefore, it's not behaving as you had intended.

To better illustrate the problem, the `date` variable is initialized as `Mon Oct 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`. When you call `date.getMonth()` it returns `9` indicating the 10th month in the calendar year; so incrementing the value by 1 results in setting the *day* of the `date` variable to *10*.

On the next iteration, the *month* hasn't changed, so the code re-executes `date.getMonth()` which returns `9` again, so on and so on.
 This unexpected behavior continues to repeat endlessly as the `while` condition is never satisfied.

The code should be updated to use [`setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) instead.

Comment: Thank you! setMonth() solve my problem. Very clear explanation.

Answer (score 9):

Use `setMonth()` instead of `setDate()` to sets the month of the date variable.

```
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets do it using [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) :

```
moment(sd).add(1,'month').format("MMM-YY")
```

[image]

You can find a difference between two dates

```
moment("08-31-2017").diff(moment("01-31-2017"), 'months', true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please DO NOT just add the month by 1!

It may break in some situations because each month has different days.

The more secure way is like following:

```js
date.setDate(1);
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
```

You may ask why do we have to do `date.setDate(1);`?
It is because there are different days in each month. If today is Oct 31 and you add the month by 1, then it will become Nov 31. However, Nov 31 is not a valid date...

Here is a rainy example for how it will break in this situation:

```js
const date = new Date(2022, 9, 31); // Oct 31st
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(date); // It returns "Dec 1st"
```